# PHP in array for just start of array element

Tags: php, arrays, contains

I have this code:

```
$array = array("Keys,placeholder", "Cheese,placeholder", "Knees,placeholder");

if(in_array("Cheese", $array)) {
    print("We do indeed have cheese!");
}

else {
    print("No cheese, Gromit!");
}
```

But when it checks the array it checks if the whole thing is 'Cheese' not just if it contains the text 'Cheese'.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

EDIT: Also, I only want the code to be triggered if just the first bit contains cheese; so for this example:

```
$array = array("Keys,placeholder", "Placeholder,cheese", "Knees,placeholder");

if(in_array("Cheese", $array)) {
    print("We do indeed have cheese!");
}

else {
    print("No cheese, Gromit!");
}
```

I don't want the code to be triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`implode` it:

```
if (strpos(implode('', $array),'Cheese')!==false) print("We do indeed have cheese!");
else print("No cheese, Gromit!");
```

ok, for Cheese being first, go:

```
... implode('|', $array), '|Cheese') ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working for the first part of my question but does not comply with the edit I just made.

Comment: It seems that the code is still always being fired (I changed | to ,).

Comment: @CHRIS don't use `,`. Your imploded $array contains `"Keys,placeholder,Placeholder,cheese,Knees,placeholder"` and will therefore find `",cheese"`. use some other character that won't be contained in your array...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("/Cheese/i", $array)) {
  return true;
}
```

Try something like this

Comment: Thanks but I get this warning when I use the code: Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given on line 3

Comment: preg_match wants a string. you could `preg_match('somepattern',implode('',$array)) though...